# Default issue view in GitHub

Tags: github, github-issues

When I click on the Issues button for a repository, the default filter is:

```
is:open is:issue
```

Is there a way to change the default so that a particular milestone is excluded? For instance:

```
is:open is:issue -milestone:foo
```

I know that I can create a bookmark, but I normally navigate to that page using the links on GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully you've found a good workaround by now, but if not, you can use a bookmarklet to exclude a milestone (or change any other search parameter).  Unfortunately GitHub doesn't allow you to change the default search query.

Add this bit of code as a bookmark in your browser, and when you go to the Issues page for any repository, just click the bookmark and it will exclude whichever milestone(s) you want.

```
javascript:
(function(){
    document.getElementById('js-issues-search').value = 'is:issue is:open -milestone:foo';
})();
```

Just change `foo` to whichever milestone you wish to exclude.